# What's a word like "misquote" but for paraphrasing?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I recently found myself saying something along the lines of

> I may have misquoted him.

but then realized I never claimed to have given a direct quote. Is there a word that's more appropriate to use in place of misquoted if you (for lack of a better word) "mis-paraphrase" someone?

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus? Most of the synonyms for misquote are more applicable to paraphrasing.

Answer (score -1):

Several of the [thesaurus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/misquote) entries for "misquote" apply well to paraphrasing and other approximate quotes.

> misreport, misrepresent, misstate, pervert